# Jquery: click does not use parameters outside function

Tags: jquery, onclick, parameter-passing

I'm using the following script to hide a checkbox when it is checked. After that, it should display the corresponding select box. If more info is needed, [check my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021931/swap-to-select-box-once-checkbox-is-checked) on the first steps.

The script does hide the checkbox, however, it does not show the correct select box. This is because it has the wrong parameters inside the click function. It always grabs the last i and the last c.

```
var userList = <?php echo json_encode($userIdList); ?>;

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i in userList) {
        for (c = 0; c <= 6; c++) { 
            $("#" + userList[i] + "_" + c).click(function(e) {
                if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $("#" + userList[i] + "_select_" + c).show();
                }
            })  
        }
    }
})
```

Who can tell me how to give the part inside the `.click` the right corresponding parameters?

```js
var userList = [1,2,4];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i in userList) {
            for (c = 0; c <= 6; c++) { 
                $("#" + userList[i] + "_" + c).click(function(e) {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                        $(this).hide();
                        $("#" + userList[i] + "_select_" + c).show();
                    }
                })  
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td>Week</td><td>Werknemer</td><td>Maandag</td><td>Dinsdag</td><td>Woensdag</td><td>Donderdag</td><td>Vrijdag</td><td>Zaterdag</td><td>Zondag</td></tr> <tr><td>DEFAULT</td><td>Lex</td> <td></td> <td><input id="1_1" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="display: none;"> <select id="1_select_1" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td></td> <td><input id="1_3" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> <select id="1_select_3" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="1_4" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="1_select_4" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="1_5" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="1_select_5" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="1_6" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="6"> <select id="1_select_6" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td></td></tr> <tr><td>DEFAULT</td><td>Virgil</td> <td><input id="2_0" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="0"> <select id="2_select_0" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="2_1" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <select id="2_select_1" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="2_2" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"> <select id="2_select_2" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="2_3" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="3" style="display: none;"> <select id="2_select_3" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="2_4" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="2_select_4" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="2_5" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="2_select_5" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td></td> <td></td></tr> <tr><td>DEFAULT</td><td>Franco</td> <td></td> <td></td> <td><input id="4_2" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"> <select id="4_select_2" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="4_3" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="3" style="display: none;"> <select id="4_select_3" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="4_4" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="4_select_4" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="4_5" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="4_select_5" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td><input id="4_6" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="6"> <select id="4_select_6" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td> <td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: add your html. turn it into a snippet.

Comment: I don't think that's possible since it's al created in laravel using the laravel forms. Also, the checkbox list is very long. However, I tried it for as far as it is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big issue with your code is that your variables `c` and `i` were declared to a higher scope than need be. Instead of using `var` or nothing, use the `let` declarative. They weren't scoped to their executing blocks and when they were used they would pull the previous information stored, causing the same box to appear over and over on click - scoping them removes this problem.

Instead of using `in` iteration you can use `of` since you're just pulling out the number stored within the array.

Another issue was that you were using `c < 6` which may be fine if your user has 6 items associated with the same id number, but in order to make sure that the number is always correct we simply search for the number of items associated with that id ahead of time and count them. This allows us to say `c < listLength` and thus makes it more dynamic.

```
var userList = [1, 2, 4];

$(document).ready(function() {

  for (let i of userList) {

    let listLength = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='" + i + "']").length;

    for (let c = 0; c < listLength; c++) {

      $("#" + i + "_" + c).click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          $(this).hide();
          console.log(i, c);
          $("#" + i + "_select_" + c).show();
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```js
var userList = [1, 2, 4];

$(document).ready(function() {

  for (let i of userList) {
 
    let listLength = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='" + i + "']").length;

    for (let c = 0; c < listLength; c++) {

      $("#" + i + "_" + c).click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          $(this).hide();
          console.log(i, c);
          $("#" + i + "_select_" + c).show();
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Week</td>
      <td>Werknemer</td>
      <td>Maandag</td>
      <td>Dinsdag</td>
      <td>Woensdag</td>
      <td>Donderdag</td>
      <td>Vrijdag</td>
      <td>Zaterdag</td>
      <td>Zondag</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEFAULT</td>
      <td>Lex</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="1_1" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="display: none;"> <select id="1_select_1" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="1_3" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> <select id="1_select_3" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="1_4" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="1_select_4" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="1_5" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="1_select_5" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="1_6" name="1_[]" type="checkbox" value="6"> <select id="1_select_6" name="1_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEFAULT</td>
      <td>Virgil</td>
      <td><input id="2_0" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="0"> <select id="2_select_0" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="2_1" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <select id="2_select_1" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="2_2" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"> <select id="2_select_2" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="2_3" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="3" style="display: none;"> <select id="2_select_3" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="2_4" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="2_select_4" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="2_5" name="2_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="2_select_5" name="2_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEFAULT</td>
      <td>Franco</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input id="4_2" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="2" style="display: none;"> <select id="4_select_2" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="4_3" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="3" style="display: none;"> <select id="4_select_3" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="4_4" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <select id="4_select_4" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="4_5" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <select id="4_select_5" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td><input id="4_6" name="4_[]" type="checkbox" value="6"> <select id="4_select_6" name="4_select_[]" style="display: none;"><option value="L">Large</option><option value="S">Small</option></select></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Could not help me more. Your solution is very clear, and it also teached me a lot, many thanks for that! (one detail just to know, I used 6 because the week will always have 7 days, still, many thanks for the clarification!)